# Tool to analyse files using in a website

Tags: javascript, optimization, web, analysis

A web site project was given to me. There is many CSS and JS files, but I'm not sure that everything is useful.

Do you know if there is a tool able to analyze what and for what are used this type of files, or directly a tool which optimize this files in a web project?

**Thank you.**

Comment: I guess you could use a spider/crawler so see which files are never hit.

Comment: This is off-topic. Please don't ask for off site tools.

Comment: @Halcyon I don't really know how use it...

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to inspector
2. click audit tab.
3. click web page performance check box
4. Click Run Button
5. You can find what css files are not used

Comment: It could be what I want, but the "Audit" tool only consider the actual state of the actual page. And my project is a heavy project, with many, many pages and I'd like something to analyze all in one step.